# httpwebrequest fails on azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've this method to perform a POST request:

```
public static string GetHttp(string url, Dictionary<string, string> query)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
        foreach(var e in query)
        {
            outgoingQueryString.Add(e.Key, e.Value);
        }

        string postData = outgoingQueryString.ToString();
        request.Method = "POST";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        var sp = request.ServicePoint;
        var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
        Encoding.Convert(
            Encoding.UTF8,
            Encoding.GetEncoding(
                Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
                new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty),
                new DecoderExceptionFallback()
                ),
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString)
        ));
    }
}
```

This code does its job on almost all url, but on certain websites, and only on azure, sometimes i get a timeout error. If the request is performed via a WebClient instead of an HttpWebRequest I get this error:

> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xxx.xxx:80]
>      System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +395
>      System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +515
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +58935447

I tried to configure a keep-alive connection but this doesn't resolve the issue:

```
            request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 12;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Timeout = 240000;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 240000, 240000);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Comment: How many requests per second against the remote server are we talking about here? Or is this just a test site with like 1 POST every minute or so?

Comment: From 1 to more than 100.

Comment: Do you see those failed connections in the firewall logs at the other end? There's also this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2015/07/13/azure-snat/ - but it's probably too soon to blame it on SNAT.